# python numpy meshgrid order

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use numpy meshgrid for a machine learning problem and it behaves as expected for a 2D mesh, where the first column is varied for each value of the 2nd column domain. However when I use meshgrid for 4 parameters, there seems to be a weird order where it varies the last column whilst holding the other 3 constant, then the second last, then the 1st column and finally the second. This resulted in me getting a result that was rotated 90 degrees from what it should have been.

I have taken the meshgrid and played around with it on its own for demonstration

```
    import numpy as np


def gen_sample_grid(npx=200, npy=200, lower_lim = 0, upper_lim=1):

  x1line = np.linspace(1, 10, npx)
  x2line = np.linspace(1, 10, npy)
  
  x3line = np.linspace(1, 10, npx)
  x4line = np.linspace(1, 10, npy)

  x1grid, x2grid, x3grid, x4grid = np.meshgrid(x1line, x2line, x3line, x4line)
#   x1grid, x2grid = np.meshgrid(x1line, x2line)
  Xgrid = np.array([x1grid, x2grid, x3grid, x4grid]).reshape([4,npx**2 * npy**2]).T
#   Xgrid = np.array([x1grid, x2grid]).reshape([2,npx*npy]).T
  return Xgrid


npx = 2
npy = 2
Xgrid = gen_sample_grid(npx, npy)
print(Xgrid)
```

The output for this simplified 4D problem is this

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. 10.]
 [ 1.  1. 10.  1.]
 [ 1.  1. 10. 10.]
 [10.  1.  1.  1.]
 [10.  1.  1. 10.]
 [10.  1. 10.  1.]
 [10.  1. 10. 10.]
 [ 1. 10.  1.  1.]
 [ 1. 10.  1. 10.]
 [ 1. 10. 10.  1.]
 [ 1. 10. 10. 10.]
 [10. 10.  1.  1.]
 [10. 10.  1. 10.]
 [10. 10. 10.  1.]
 [10. 10. 10. 10.]]
```

and for the 2D problem

```
def gen_sample_grid(npx=200, npy=200, lower_lim = 0, upper_lim=1):
# corresponding to f1
  x1line = np.linspace(1, 10, npx)
  x2line = np.linspace(1, 10, npy)
  
# corresponding to f2
#   x3line = np.linspace(1, 10, npx)
#   x4line = np.linspace(1, 10, npy)

#   x1grid, x2grid, x3grid, x4grid = np.meshgrid(x1line, x2line, x3line, x4line)
  x1grid, x2grid = np.meshgrid(x1line, x2line)
#   Xgrid = np.array([x1grid, x2grid, x3grid, x4grid]).reshape([4,npx**2 * npy**2]).T
  Xgrid = np.array([x1grid, x2grid]).reshape([2,npx*npy]).T
  return Xgrid


npx = 2
npy = 2
Xgrid = gen_sample_grid(npx, npy)
print(Xgrid)
```

The output is this:

```
[[ 1.  1.]
 [10.  1.]
 [ 1. 10.]
 [10. 10.]]
```

Is there a way that I can make the 3rd and 4th columns in the 4d meshgrid behave like the 1st and 2nd columns (i.e. the way the 2d problem behaves) ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `indexing`:

```
In [65]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(2),np.arange(3),np.arange(4))[0].shape
Out[65]: (3, 2, 4)
In [66]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(2),np.arange(3),np.arange(4),indexing='ij')[0].sh
    ...: ape
Out[66]: (2, 3, 4)
```

There's a lengthy `note` in its docs that explains this parameter.